# SQL FK constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I have 2 tables, Office and User. I want to make relation OneToMany (1 office has many users).

But when i run this sql

```
ALTER TABLE izo_user ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DA8075CFFA0C224 FOREIGN KEY (office_id) REFERENCES izo_office (id)
CREATE INDEX IDX_DA8075CFFA0C224 ON izo_user (office_id)
```

something goes wrong and i get error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`izoplast`.`#sql-9842_1be9`, CONSTRAINT `FK_DA8075CFFA0C224` FOREIGN KEY (`office_id`) REFERENCES `izo_office` (`id`))
```

My Tables: http://oi57.tinypic.com/whhezr.jpg

Comment: Do you have records in `izo_user` that don't exist in `izo_office`? Try running the following and if it returns results then that is what your problem is - `SELECT DISTINCT u.office_id FROM izo_user AS u LEFT JOIN izo_office AS o ON o.id = u.office_id WHERE o.id IS NULL;`

Answer (score 0):

try it if it works for you-

```
ALTER TABLE izo_user add index idx_office_id(office_id);
ALTER TABLE izo_user ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DA8075CFFA0C224 FOREIGN KEY (office_id) REFERENCES izo_office (id);
```